# WCF[Internet scenario]. Fastest way transmit\serialize(de) data

Tags: c#, wcf, optimization

My wcf is hosted by IIS and used basicHttpBinding.
My common data is datasets, whci I should serialize and transmit to client.
I haven't got hundreads of MB, but I want to trnasmit it to client with best perfomance.

As I understand I should use MTOM encoding. Right?

Also want to know about type of transmitting object:
DataSet, Byte[], Gzip Stream (by IIS or manually).

I think my scenario is rather common. Want to hear your working fast design.

Comment: Best performance?? **Don't** use DataSets - they have big overhead.... use straight lists of objects instead....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the *fastest* way to do this would be with protobuf-net via a DTO (instead of data-table). Protobuf-net can plug into WCF with just config file changes and had demonstrably the smallest output and fastest processing of any general purpose serializer I know of. I may be biased (I wrote that version) but it is free, so worth a try.

But no data-tables.

And yea, MTOM helps when passing binary (which protobuf is), but not XML (so MTOM with standard DataTable is pointless)

Comment: (I can supply a recent SO question on comparative WCF serializer performance as supporting evidence if you like)

Comment: Marc, thanks a lot. Yeah, can u be so kind give me this link. Also want to ask. if I want pass result of db queries to client I should put result of queries in dtos, and pass to client with (binary protobuf). Ok. But if I haven't got any ORM for get db results to domains and map into dto, and my db query results are just xml string. How should I pass to client this(without object collection)?

Comment: @andrew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790728/performance-tests-of-serializations-used-by-wcf-bindings/3793091#3793091

Comment: re the other: if you want the best performance, the client will have to know in advance what it is expecting. In many cases you can share the DTO between client and server