# Sending a HashSet to a C# ApiController

Tags: c#, hashset, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a C# object `MyObject` with a `HashSet` property. I serialise it client-side, and then send it via `GET` with parameters in the URI to a C# `ApiController`, which accepts the object as an argument:

```
public MyOtherObject Get([FromUri] MyObject obj) { ... }
```

This all worked absolutely fine using a `List`, but now that I'm using a `HashSet`, the client serialises and sends the object, but the server receives an empty `HashSet`.

Is there a key difference in the way that C#'s `ApiController` receives `HashSets` and `Lists` via URI?

Comment: How do you send it and how do you serialize it/deserialize it.

Comment: what is the structure of `MyObject`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192905/serializing-a-hashset

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, the object is a POCO with a few primitive types and a couple of `HashSet`s, all as public properties.

Comment: @Bauss I should have been more specific: I'm not actually serialising; I'm parameterising by using RestSharp's "AddParameter" function, to put the object directly in the URI. At the other end, the object is deparameterised through whatever magic `FromUri` does.