# Binary serialization/de-serialization in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, marshalling, boost-serialization

I am working on a distributed application which has two components. One is written in standard C++ (**not managed C++** and running on a Linux platform) and the other one is written in C#. Both are communicating via a message bus.

I have a situation in which I need to pass objects from C++ to C# application and for this I need to serialize those objects in C++ and de-serialize them in C# (something like marshaling/un-marshaling in .NET). I need to perform this serialization in binary and not in XML (due to performance reasons).

I have used `Boost.Serialization` to do this when both ends were implemented in C++ but now that I have a .NET application on one end, `Boost.Serialization` is not a viable solution.

I am looking for a solution that allows me to perform (de)serialization across C++ and .NET boundary i.e., **cross platform binary serialization**.

I know I can implement the (de)serialization code in a C++ dll and use `P/Invoke` in the .NET application, but I want to keep that as a last resort.

Also, I want to know if I use some standard like gzip, will that be efficient? Are there any other alternatives to gzip? What are the pros/cons of them?

Thanks

Comment: My best suggestion is to NOT do it. Use json, xml or something else to transfer your data. Implement that FIRST, if it ends up too slow then analyze what is taking time...

Comment: I started with XML serialization and it did prove slower as compared to binary serialization (with both ends running a c++ application). This is the reason I chose Boost.Serialization at the first place.

Comment: Have you considered developing a simple COM application, C++ and .NET supports COM technology as far as I know.

Comment: Check out my blog post about different formats and performance - http://maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gzip won't *directly* help with serialization - it will just (attempt to) shrink a stream. This *may* help, or not, depending on the amount of duplicated data in the stream. For dense data with little text, I've seen gzip *increase* the size of the payload.

Personally I would look at [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) here (but I'm biased, as I'm one of the authors of the [many extensions](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns)). You typically (but not always) define the messages in a basic language (a .proto file), and run language-specific tools to generate the classes. Performance is very good - focusing on .NET it can **far** exceed the inbuilt serializers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790728/performance-tests-of-serializations-used-by-wcf-bindings/3793091#3793091) [2](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) [3](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) )

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend Protocol Buffers, which is Googles own serialization library. It has both .Net, C++ and Java serializers. Most implementations are also quite fast.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd look into it.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), it has even more backends and if necessary provides a good part of the code required for network communication - in case you want to scale out.

If you only want easy object serialization I would have a look at json.org There are plenty of C++ / .NET implementations around.