# map and shared_ptr serialization between C# and C++ applications?

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, thrift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary serialization/de-serialization in C++ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677669/binary-serialization-de-serialization-in-c-and-c)

I am working on a project where server is written in C++ (boost is extensively used) and the client application is written in C#. I am facing the problem while serializing/deserializing messages between client/server.

I have studied various alternative libraries for achieving this sort of cross-platform serialization, and Protocol Buffers seems to be the best... but it does not support serialization of the standard library's `map` container and `boost::shared_ptr`.

My question then, is:

- Can someone explain how `map` and `boost::shared_ptr` could be serialized using Protocol Buffers. Or failing that,
- Would Apache's Thrift work for this?
- ...Or am I stuck using interop DLLs on the (C#) client side?

Comment: @jgauffin: NOT a duplicate (of that question at least), since this user is explicitly ruling out protocol buffers.

Comment: I don't see how any implementation would serialize a `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

What about wrapping the c++ message classes with c++/cli  ref classes so that you use the same boost serialisation library on the client side.