# How to Use BinaryFormatter in windows phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-phone-7.1

How can I use BinaryFormatter in Windows Phone 7.

I use this `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` in service1.svc.cs but I can't use this Reference in windows phone 7.

Is there any solution to this?

My Code For DeserializeObject

```
 public static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] xml)
    {
        BinaryFormatter xs = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xml);
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
```

BinaryFormatter gives error in windows phone 7. So how can I **Deserialize**. What changes that I have to do in this code?

Comment: There is no solution with your service as written. You'll have to change the service to use a serialization format which is supported in Windows Phone 7. If your service is WCF why aren't you using the DataContractSerializer and letting WCF handle the serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 6):

As @driis mentioned, you cannot use `BinaryFormatter` on Windows Phone. You can use the binary *encoding* in a WCF endpoint (i.e., an endpoint whose binding is a custom binding with the `BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement` and the `HttpTransportBindingElement`), and that will be supported on WP7. You just cannot use the binary formatter there.

*Update following comment*: 
Looking at your code, it's not only that code that needs to be changed - you need to change the **service** code as well, to serialize an object in a format which is supported in Silverlight. You can use the `DataContractSerializer`, with a binary reader / writer, or you can use another library which is supported in both cases. For example, the code below should work in both desktop and SL versions:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] xml) 
{ 
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xml))
    {
        using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(
            memoryStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)dcs.ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And on the server:

```
public static byte[] SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms))
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            dcs.WriteObject(writer, obj);
            writer.Flush();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code give me error like this. Message = "Type 'System.Net.PathList' with data contract name 'PathList:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net' 

is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types

Comment: What type of object are you trying to serialize?

Comment: A cookie container is not serializable by the default serializers in SL, so you can either choose another serializer (IIRC it can be serialized by Newtonsoft's JSON.NET), or you can choose to use a Data Transfer Object to convert between the cookie container and a data type which can be serialized.

Comment: How can I Serialize and Deserialize using JSON.net. can you please give me code for this?

Comment: Can U please check your code that u post as answer. It not work fine it gives error. or can please give me code  for this using json.net. please I work on this error from last 5 days. yet I have not solved it

Answer (score 2):

BinaryFormatter is not supported in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: You cannot. You need to switch to a serialization engine that is supported on both platforms. Perhaps protobuf-net, see the accepted answer here for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091712/binaryformatter-does-not-exist-in-cf-solutions

Answer (score 0):

There is no library support for binary serialization on WP 7.1. as driis mentioned.

You should rather use `XmlObjectSerializer` instead, or even one of it's subclasses that support serialization of most common API objects, like contacts data, or such.

If you checked `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace assembly (ex. in Visual Studio's object browser) you'd found hierarchy of adequate classes.

And why do you care about serialization method? XML serialization is more portable, more uniform and easier to read by a human.

Comment: I am new so I don't know how to use this I Post my code in my question

Comment: carlosfigueira have posted a very sensible answer to dispel your doubts. Use his solution as it looks good (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12376808/1598508).