# Deserialize byte[] object using XmlSerializer

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7.1, xml-deserialization

Here is my code for Deserializer for byte[] object

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] xml)
{
    //BinaryFormatter xs = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream memoryStream=new MemoryStream(xml);
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
}
```

It gives error `There is an error in XML document`

**InnerException** `Invalid character in the given encoding`

How can I Deserialize it?

Calling funcation:

```
    void svc_Get_Conn(object send, GetConnCompletedEventArgs e)
    {  
        CookieContainer con =DeserializeObject<CookieContainer>(e.Result);
    }
```

Following funcation is from **Service1.svc.cs**

```
public static byte[] SerializeObject<T>(T obj) 
    { 
        try 
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) 
            { 
                BinaryFormatter xs = new BinaryFormatter(); 
                xs.Serialize(memoryStream, obj); 
                return memoryStream.ToArray(); 
            } 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Pass in valid XML data? It sounds like a possible *encoding mismatch*. Try to convert the `byte[]` to an appropriate `string` or `StringReader` first.

Comment: Uh - it sounds like your byte[] array might not be valid XML.  SUGGESTION: Look at the bytes.

Comment: Ok.I edit my code please check it

Comment: Can you show us how the contents of the byte array is constructed?

Comment: @PeterLillevold check it in code

Comment: @Ajay, please don't post the same question twice. This is the same issue you have in http://stackoverflow.com/q/12376765/751090.

Answer (score 3):

**XmlSerializer can't be used to deserialize something created with BinaryFormatter<sup>1</sup>.**

Solutions:

1. Use XmlSerializer to *serialize* the data, or;
2. Use BinaryFormatter to *deserialize* the data, or;
3. Use an alternative for serialization *and* deserialization.

Alternatives include [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), which both offer .NET Compact Framework (Windows Phone) builds. There is also [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), which is standard in "normal" .NET, but I am not sure what support it has on CF.

---

<sup>1</sup> Serialization formats are generally *not interchangeable* and trying to use the non-compatible pair in this case makes as much sense as serializing as JSON and trying to deserialize as ANS.1 (something distinctly not JSON).

[XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> Serializes and deserializes objects into and from **XML documents.**

[BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx):

> Serializes and deserializes [objects into and from] **[an internal] binary format.**

Comment: I can't use BinaryFormatter in Windows phone 7

Comment: So then don't use it. Use XmlSerializer (or Json.NET or even Protobuf.NET) and call it a day.