# How to minimalize size of serialized data

Tags: c#, performance, serialization

I need to minimalize size of serialized class. As I understand size of serialized data depends on names of properties.
So class

```
class XYZ
{
public int X { get;set;}
}
```

is smaller after serialization than

```
class XYZ
{
public int NumberOfUsersWithAccessToReportingService { get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way to mimimalize size of second class without changing names of properties to shorter versions like in first example? I need this to store data in Server.Cache so it is binary serialization.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ could be a good candidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If size is your aim, something terse like protobuf would be good; consider some measures: [Performance Tests of Serializations used by WCF Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790728/performance-tests-of-serializations-used-by-wcf-bindings/3793091#3793091)

In your case, using protobuf-net:

```
[ProtoContract]
class XYZ
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int NumberOfUsersWithAccessToReportingService { get;set;}
}
```

The size doesn't depend on the member-names, it is pure-binary, there are no text overheads, and it uses efficient encodings for most data types. Example usage:

```
using(var file = File.Create(path))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(file, obj);
}
...
using(var file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<YourType>(file);
}
```

In fact, the above type will be somewhere between 2 and 6 bytes, depending on the value of the property (integers close to 0 take less space).

Comment: @Korin - to be fair, while I might have *implemented* that one, the *design* there was Google...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XML Serialisation, yes you can:

```
class XYZ
{
    [XmlElement("X")]
    public int NumberOfUsersWithAccessToReportingService { get;set;}
}
```

if it is a binary serialization, there is no need for it.

Comment: re your last line; that isn't quite true, or rather: it depends on the serializer. protobuf won't care, but BinaryFormatter uses field-names, and field-names *generally* depend on property-names, especially for automatically implemented properties.